# vue2 component bundled for vue3 use class issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, rollup, rollupjs

I'm using a component that comes from my design-system in vue 2,
I bundle it in vue3 with rollup to make it works with my front-end app.

For no apparent reason the class is not applied thus the style neither.

See below the component with the class

```html
<div v-else-if="!isFolder">
  <BIMDataCheckbox
    :disabled="disabled"
    v-if="multiSelect"
    :modelValue="selected"
    class="file-card__content__header__btn-menu__checkbox"
  />
  <BIMDataRadio
    :disabled="disabled"
    v-else
    big
    :modelValue="selected"
    name="BIMDataFileCardRadio"
  />
</div>
```

In a other front-end app in vue 2 where I also import the design-system the component works like a charm

any suggestion ?

Comment: What do you see in your devtools? The class is maybe overwritten? Is there any CSS related to that component at all?

Comment: in devtools I can only see the default class given by the component "bimdata-checkbox", but no tracks of "file-card__content__header__btn-menu__checkbox"

Comment: Do style properties end up in your build?